# AWS Boto3 send_command() always fails on Ubuntu "An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

I'm using boto3 to create an EC2 instance and then `send_command()` to send Linux commands to execute. I created an IAM role and pass this to `create_instances()`.

For the Amazon Linux AMI `ami-0329eac6c5240c99d` it works 99% of the time.
For the Ubuntu 22.04 AMI `ami-0b828c1c5ac3f13ee` it fails every time.

I get this error:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred
> (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances
> [[<my_instance_id>]] not in a valid state for account
> <my_account_id>

This Ubuntu page implies the SSM Agent should work when passing an IAM role via `create_instances()`:

> Every instance of Ubuntu server and Ubuntu Pro server comes with the AWS Systems Manager (SSM) agent installed. To enable it, it is only necessary to attach an IAM role that will allow the agent to interact with SSM.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-use-aws-ssm-session-manager-for-accessing-ubuntu-pro-instances#1-overview

1. Should Ubuntu 22.04 work with SSM by default?
2. Why does this occasionally happen with Amazon AMI too?

Comment: Did you check any ssm logs on the instance?

Comment: Do the instances have the same instance role?

Comment: @Paolo yes I create instances using the same role/I only have one role permitting SSM.

Comment: @Marcin I didn't know there was such a thing. Is it possible to enable (and view) SSM error logging on the Python side calling `send_command()`, or only by going on the instance?

Answer (score 0):

InvalidInstanceId would means the Instance is not SSM managed on the same region you are sending the Send_Command.

I would suggest that after you launch the instance and attach the IAM role with the required permissions, ensuring you are launching it in a public subnet with a public IP address attached so that SSM service endpoints can be reached by the instance  ( or alternatively, if you have configured NAT to connect), verify if the Instance is SSM managed before sending the send_command.

To verify if the Instance is SSM managed, assert https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceInformation.html#systemsmanager-Type-InstanceInformation-PingStatus to Online.

To troubleshoot why instance is not getting managed, see https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ec2-instance-not-appear